# Should order matter in this where clause?

Tags: mysql

I'm getting different results by changing the order of my WHERE conditions, but I don't see why:

```
SELECT 
    ...

WHERE (
    -- Ramps that start this month
    (r.start_dte > ? AND r.start_dte <= ?)

    OR

    -- Ramps that end this month and have no follow-up.
    (r.end_dte >= ? AND r.end_dte <= ? AND r.id = m.latestId)
)

-- Throw out expired schedules or contracts
AND (s.term_dte > r.start_dte or s.term_dte is null)
AND (c.term_dte > r.start_dte or c.term_dte is null)

-- Throw out a ramp if its end date is before its start date
AND (r.end_dte > r.start_dte)

AND s.name not like '%zz%'
```

My intention is for ONE of the first two conditions to be met (a ramp must either start this month, or end this month & have no follow-up), and ALL of the other conditions to be met. Have I not written this?

I know things aren't working correctly, since I'm getting results that violate the second-to-last `AND` condition.

Comment: Your second and second-to-last clauses are in conflict. Why say (A OR B) and then say (A)? Where A is s.term_dte > r.start_dte.

Comment: Sorry, I meant r.end_dte. The second to last clause says, only get ramps whose end dates come after their start dates. The second clause says, only get ramps whose end dates fall between a time range. I don't think they're in conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that in the fifth clause

```
AND (r.start_dte < r.end_dte)
```

I forgot that `r.end_dte` could be null. This was giving me strange results. I changed it to

```
AND (r.start_dte < r.end_dte OR r.end_dte is null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question: yes, to me your query looks to be correct with respect to your specification.

For your second question, I'd suggest to rewrite your conditions such that they comply to number-line ordering (smaller date/value on left-hand side):

```
...
WHERE (
    -- Ramps that start this month
    (? < r.start_dte AND r.start_dte <= ?)

    OR

    -- Ramps that end this month and have no follow-up.
    (? <= r.end_dte AND r.end_dte <= ? AND r.id = m.latestId)
)

-- Throw out expired schedules or contracts
AND (r.start_dte < s.term_dte or s.term_dte is null)  -- condition (3)
AND (r.start_dte < c.term_dte or c.term_dte is null)

-- Throw out a ramp if its end date is before its start date
AND (r.start_dte < s.term_dte)  -- condition (5)

AND s.name not like '%zz%'
```

Now you can see that condition (3) is weaker than condition (5) and therefore **either** (3) is redundant and can be omitted **or** (5) is too strong and wrongfully filters out results.

Comment: I mis-typed, condition (5) is `r.start_dte < r.end_dte`. I am still getting confusing results.

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks for your advice regarding number-line ordering. It makes things clearer.